# Fineuploader issues with Norton AV

Tags: fine-uploader

We are noticing users with Norton antivirus aren't able to upload direct to Aws s3. There is a 403 error thrown on the s3 url. We have traced this to being very specifically Norton users only and happens in both ie and chrome

here are the console errors

```
request for 0
https://****.s3.amazonaws.com/****.mp4?uploads Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
custom.fineuploader-5.0.9.min.js:25 [Fine Uploader 5.0.9] POST request for 0 has failed - response code 403
custom.fineuploader-5.0.9.min.js:25 [Fine Uploader 5.0.9] Specific problem detected initiating multipart upload request for 0: 'The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.'.
custom.fineuploader-5.0.9.min.js:25 [Fine Uploader 5.0.9] Chunked upload request failed for 0, chunk 0

**** used in place of real information
```

Answer (score 1):

The log messages (added after the question was posted) suggest that the issue is with a clock drift on the user's machine. It's not clear how this is related to Norton. If the clock on the user's machine drifts too far from the actual time, then AWS will reject the request. You'll need to be sure that the machine clock is reasonably accurate.

A similar question was asked at [Fine Uploader getting "Policy expired" message sending to S3 for some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520108/fine-uploader-getting-policy-expired-message-sending-to-s3-for-some).