# AWS S3 upload. Invalid according to Policy: Policy expired

Tags: django, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I'm using a Django server hosted on EC2 Singapore. I'm also using an S3 bucket to save files uploaded through the Django Admin panel. To upload files, I'm using `django-s3direct`.

When I upload files using my local machine on Eastern American time, it prevents me from uploading the files citing:

```
<Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy expired.</Message>
```

I've tried the solutions from: 
[Fine Uploader getting "Policy expired" message sending to S3 for some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520108/fine-uploader-getting-policy-expired-message-sending-to-s3-for-some) and here: https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1387

When I check the uploaded time and the UTC time, there's no difference. How do I fix this error?

EDIT: To be noted, the upload works perfectly on localhost but doesn't work on the server hosted on AWS EC2.

Comment: If the question is still actual.. Have you checked system clock settings?

Comment: Most likely the machine your are browsing from has an inaccurate clock. The server is irrelevant.

Comment: As @RayNicholus said, it is most likely an inaccurate clock. Beware of the fact that it isn't the time zone that is taken into account here, but the clock itself.

Comment: @RayNicholus This problem is persisting across multiple machines.

Comment: @Ghislaindj This problem is persisting across multiple machines.

Comment: @Newtt I don't think time zones are a factor here. If that was improperly handled by Fine Uploader or AWS, there would have been a flood of support tickets.

Answer (score 2):

Similar issues refer to an inaccurate clock. This should be the clock of the client not the server. I suggest writing code to check whether client's time in sync with a known and accurate time server. If the time is out of sync, a friendly message can be shown to the user to update the system's clock.  If the time is in sync, you can then proceed with the upload.

Comment: Or you can use [Fine Uploader S3's clock drift feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/s3.html#accounting-for-browserclient-clock-drift) to account for the out-of-sync clock on the client machine.